# Div fixed height but dynamic width

Tags: html, html-table, width, wicket

I'm using wicket and have a dynamic table. What I want to be able to do is have a fixed table  border height that adds rows (max 5 per page), and it's row's width can grow dynamically so something like:

Column Headers

row1

row2

empty space

end of table

The only solution I can think of (Which probably isn't the best because I'm a novice at both wicket and html) is to have a div with a fixed height, and growable width. The div will provide the table's fixed boxed border, and the table itself will be inside this div, allowing it's rows to grow dynamically by wicket with a pageable view setting a max of 5 rows.

so far I have:

html:

```
      <div class="tableCell">
   <table border="1" BORDERCOLOR="#333">
     <tr>
       <th>SSA ID</th>
       <th>Default Qualifier</th>
       <th colspan="2">Property Name/Value</th>
       <th>Description</th>
     </tr>
     <div wicket:id="SSAIDs">
       <tr>
         <td wicket:id="SSAID">test</td>
         <td wicket:id="defaultQaulifier">test</td>
         <td wicket:id="propertyName">test</td>
         <td wicket:id="propertyValue">test</td>     
         <td class="width" wicket:id="description">test</td> 
         <td><a href="#">Edit</a> 
           <a href="#">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbspDelete</a>
           <a href="#">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbspView Roles</a>
         </td>
       </tr>
     </div><!-- end SSAID's div -->
```

and for CSS no matter what I try, I can get the height to be fixed but the width will always expand to the end of the page.. This div is currently inside of a container class..

If you don't know Wicket, that is fine.. I just need to know how to make the div that contains the table wrap its width, but have a fixed height.

Comment: I ended up just leaving the table and Div border off, and making the cells bordered by overriding: td { outline:#333 solid thin; outline-width:.5px; } th { outline:#333 solid thin; outline-width:.5px; } tr { outline:#333 solid thin; outline-width:.5px; } and then just left the height and with static. This way looks nice as well, and the width still grows dynamically without being enclosed by a border as I originally wanted.

Comment: Not sure what you are needing, but you could use a SimpleAttributeModifier to control the width of an element from your Java Code. If you are looking for controlling the width from html, you should not tag with "wicket", if you are trying to control the width from the Java code, test adding something like this to your div component: yourDiv.add(new SimpleAttributeModifier("style", "width:" + customWidth + "px;")); You can also manipulate classes if you want it cleaner...